# Reverse Vector Layer Feature order

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a vector layer where some features are found entirely within other features and therefore I can't select that feature because the other feature is on top of it. Is there a way to reverse the order of the features of a vector layer after they have already been loaded? This will likely solve about 99% of issues that may occur with my mouseover popup.

**Edit to add code:**

I'm trying to do this on demand after the layer is already loaded.

```
var refreshStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh( {
    interval : 60 * 1000
  });   
var vLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Hazards with Population",
      {
        projection : "EPSG:4326",
        strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), refreshStrategy],
        protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP(
        {          
          url : "./getFeatures.php",              
          format : new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(),
          rendererOptions : {
            zIndexing : true
          }
        })
      });
```

Comment: How are you currently getting your data/what have you got at the moment? What is the problem preventing you from reversing the data you are stuffing into the layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you have access and can modify your `getFeatures.php`, simply reverse the array where the data is being formatted as GeoJSON.

If it's coming from a database, reverse your `order by` clauses. Or if it's coming from some other source, reverse the array just before formatting it as GeoJSON:

```
$data = array(item1, item2, item3, ...); // Your array of data the way it's loaded currently
$reversed = array_reverse($data); // Reverse the array
makeGeoJSON($reversed); // Transfor it into GeoJSON the way you're doing currently
```

If you don't have access to the php code, you probably can achieve the same effect by adding an event listener to the `beforefeaturesadded` event on the layer:

```
vectorLayer.events.register('beforefeaturesadded', vectorLayer, function (data) {
    data.features.reverse();
});
```

Comment: That would be nice, but I don't have access to the getFeatures.php. I was hoping there was a javascript way to flip the feature order.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a javascript-only solution.

Comment: Thanks Rene! I should have been more clear in my initial question. I already have them loaded and want to switch them after the load. Like when a user fires an event. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @René Wolferink is right. `featureArrayList.reverse()` should help you...